# Only the last value from the list of values retrieved from MySQL is stored in the variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to fetch a list of values from MySQL table using `query1` and then use them in `query2` to fetch values. `Query1` gives 4 values however `Query2` gives output matching the last value of `Query1`.

Following is my controller code

```
public function example_ctl(){
  $data['result'] = $this->some_model->example();
}
```

Following is my model code

```
public function example() {

        $query = "select m.queue_id from agent_queue_mapping_table as m, user_table as u where u.id=m.user_id and m.company_id = ".$this->session->userdata('user_comp_id')." and u.id = ".$this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $res = $this->db->query($query); 

        foreach ($res->result_array() as $value) {
            $queue_ids = implode(',', $value);
        }

        $query_ticket = "select * from tickets_table where company_id = ".$this->session->userdata('user_comp_id')." and ticket_status = 'New' and queue_id IN (".$queue_ids.") ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
        $res_ticket = $this->db->query($query_ticket);  
        return $res_ticket->result_array();

 }
```

I'm not able to understand where I'm going wrong. Please help.

Comment: What is in your view?

Comment: you can use join for same. check what is output of $this->last->query();

Comment: your query is wrong, you are missing JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed this issue.

```
$query = "select m.queue_id from agent_queue_mapping_table as m, user_table as u where u.id=m.user_id and m.company_id = ".$this->session->userdata('user_comp_id')." and u.id = ".$this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $res = $this->db->query($query); 

        foreach ($res->result_array() as $value) {
            $queue_ids[] = $value['queue_id'];
        }

        $queue_id = implode(',', $queue_ids);

        $query_ticket = "select * from tickets_table where company_id = ".$this->session->userdata('user_comp_id')." and ticket_status = 'New' and queue_id IN (".$queue_id.") ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
        $res_ticket = $this->db->query($query_ticket);  
        return $res_ticket->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code into this

```
<?php 
    $queue_id = array();
     foreach ($res->result_array() as $value) {
                $queue_id[] = $value;
            }

            $queue_id = implode(",",$value);

 ?>
```

`$queue_id` is  overridden inside the loop each time loop executes that is why you get last value